# How to modify all text elements; visual studio c++

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to create color themes for my winForms application. Essentially what will happen is you select one of the themes in the settings and the application will update with the selected color pallet.

My problem is that the program has hundreds of text elements (labels, listboxes, textboxes, etc.). Rather than writing a line of code for each text element (per color theme), I was wondering if there was some way to modify all text elements at once.

I was hoping maybe there is a way to group text elements into 'Title', 'Subtitle', 'Main', categories and then assigning the new color values to the groups.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need to design (and implement) a theming system.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Could you give more information? To my understanding, I am already trying to do that.

Comment: What I was trying to say was; you won't find an out-of-the-box solution for that, you are going to have to come up with your own. And have fun coding that; it won't be easy.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/peters/winforms-modernui

Comment: Place pointers to the text elements into an array or vector.  Iterate through the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System::Windows::Forms::Form class has a read-only property called **Controls**.  This is a collection of all child controls on the form.

In C# you can do like this.  I am pretty sure you can do the same thing in C++/CLI:

```
var cols = new Dictionary<string, Color>()
{
    { "red", Color.Red },
    { "green", Color.Green },
    { "blue", Color.Blue },
};

var theme = "green";

foreach(var ctrl in Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is TextBox)
        ((TextBox)ctrl).BackColor = cols[theme];
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try once I complete main priorities. I'm fairly new at Programming, do you happen to know the c++ equivalent off the top of your head?

Comment: Replace var with auto, new with gcnew, "." with "::", foreach(var ctrl in Controls) with for(auto& ctrl : Controls).